# Bugs in Google Code itself -- where to report?

Tags: google-code

Where does one go to report bugs in Google Code? Alas, searching for "Google Code" within "Google Code" is futile as the title of every single project page contains the words "Google Code" -- assuming that Google Code is even self-hosting.

Comment: It's come up repeatedly in the comments for Chromium issue 41467:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41467

Wherever someone types "http://", all trailing punctuation is omitted. For instance, the preceding sentence would show, in a comment for an issue in Google Code Project Hosting, like this:

  Wherever someone types "http:// all trailing punctiation is omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit [Project Hosting on Google Code group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting).

Comment: Ah, thanks -- newsgroups didn't even occur to me, after spending a few days tracking Chromium bugs through Google Code itself. It seemed obvious that there'd be a structured interface, but I suppose a newsgroup will do the trick just fine. :-)